# Why is $\gcd(a,c)=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gcd-and-lcm

Consider the $2\times2$ matrix, $A\in M_2(\mathbb Z)$:
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right)$$

Assume that $\det A = \pm 1$. Why is it true that $\gcd (a,c) = 1$?

Comment: Let $a = te$ and $c=tf$. Then $\pm 1 = ad-bc = t(ed-bf)$. For which $t$ is that possible?

Comment: Bonus: If $a,c\in\Bbb Z$ with $\gcd(a,c)=1$, then you can find $b,d$ such that $\det A=1$.

Comment: And for $A\in  M_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $\det(A) = \pm 1$ means $A^{-1} \in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ie. $A \mathbb{Z}^2 = \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: I see. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=a'm$ and $c=c'm$, where $m=\gcd(a,c)>0$; then
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\begin{pmatrix}a'm&b\\c'm&d\end{pmatrix}
=
m\det\begin{pmatrix}a'&b\\c'&d\end{pmatrix}
$$
by the properties of the determinant.

If the determinant is $\pm1$, then $m$ has to be $1$.

Similarly, $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $\gcd(c,d)=1$ and $\gcd(b,d)=1$. This easily generalizes to matrices of any size.

Answer (score 0):

you have that:
$$ad-cb=\pm1$$ 
It follows that if n divide a and c
say $a=np$ and $c=nq$ 
then n  automatically divide 1  since we get $$ad-bc= n(pd-qb)=\pm1$$
that is $n=\pm 1$.
Thus 
$gcd(a,c)=1$

Comment: $g = \gcd(a,c)$. That $g \ |\ ad-bc$ is trivial, Bezout identity says that there exist $b,d$ such that $g = ad-bc$

Comment: you are right this was even blatantly obvious